# jsp using the variable class type

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am new to advance JAVA.

i have a 3 pseudu(getters/setters) java classes whose variables are

**Class name: users**

**variables** : int userID , String Name , String email

**Class name: answers**

**variables** : int answerID , String answer , **users user**

In my jsp page , i am using JSTL tags (where answers a = new answers)

when i am trying `<c:out value = "${a.answer}"/>` works fine
when i am trying `<c:out value = "${a.answerID}"/>` works fine
However , when i am trying to get variable of answers class i.e users email like  `<c:out value = "${a.user}"/>` it fails

My question is: how can i use "user" to get his ID , name and email?

Comment: What error are you getting? Post your answers class.

Comment: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'user' not found on type com.agilemaple.common.dto.answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have this in your answers class:

```
    public users getUser() {
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: It's always best practice to have Java types (classes)name as upper case and literals of variables in class starting with small case. This is for users class name and String Name literal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it will not work u have to call like this

Try to use this

```
    <c:out value = "${a.user.id}"/>

    <c:out value = "${a.user.name}"/>

    <c:out value = "${a.user.email}"/>
```

It only works when

User class contains `id` as attribute with setters and getters and you can replace anything with `id` which should have attributes and setters and getters in Userclass